# Database constraints based on relationship dependencies

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am trying to model a tricky case in the database schema in order to avoid possible inconsistencies. The following diagram roughly describes the current situation, there are 3 tables which interact with each other, table1 and table 2 have an N:M relationship, table2 and table3 have another N:M relationship, table1 and table3 have a 1:N relationship. I need to somehow add a constraint such there can only be relationships between table2 and table3 when there also exists a relationship between table2 and the table1 which is foreign key of that particular instance of table3.

[image]

As an example, let's suppose we have the following tables:

[image]

Given the constraint I want to impose, the first row in table3_has_table2 is valid, as table3[0x000020] has table1[0x0000A] as FK and table2[0x00010] has a an entry in table1_has_table2 with table1[0x0000A], but the second row in table3_has_table2, is not valid as table2[0x00011] has no relationship with table1[0x0000A] in table1_has_table2.

Comment: In the database-design you just need to add that as a integrity contraint saying "there can only be relationships between table2 and table3 when there also exists a relationship between table2 and the table1". If you want to implement that constraint in sql you can create a trigger. I also thought about other alternatives in the database design, but i think all the other alternatives break one of the other rules, or have duplicated data (if you represent table1_has_table2 and table2_has_table3 in only one relation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your last foreign key reference is referencing the wrong table. I wrote this in PostgreSQL. For MySQL, you'll just need to move the inline constraints into separate constraint clauses.

I think these first three tables are the same as yours. (But with shorter names. If you're going to use meaningless names in your questions, at least make them short.)

```
create table t1 (
  t1_id integer primary key
);

create table t2 (
  t2_id integer primary key
);

create table t1_has_t2 (
  t1_id integer not null references t1 (t1_id),
  t2_id integer not null references t2 (t2_id),
  primary key (t1_id, t2_id)
);
```

The table "t3" is a little different. The unique constraint looks redundant, but it's not. It lets the pair of columns be the target of a foreign key reference.

```
create table t3 (
  t3_id integer primary key,
  t1_id integer not null references t1 (t1_id),
  unique (t3_id, t1_id)
);
```

And the last table, "t3_has_ts", is different enough that it needs a different kind of name. It has overlapping foreign key constraints.

```
create table t3_has_ts (
  t3_id integer not null,
  t2_id integer not null,
  t1_id integer not null,
  foreign key (t1_id, t2_id) references t1_has_t2 (t1_id, t2_id),
  foreign key (t3_id, t1_id) references t3 (t3_id, t1_id),
  primary key (t3_id, t2_id, t1_id)
);
```

I used integers for the integer columns.

```
insert into t1 values (10), (11);
insert into t2 values (16), (17);
insert into t3 values (32, 10);

insert into t1_has_t2 values (10, 16);
insert into t1_has_t2 values (11, 17);

-- This is the row you said should succeed.
insert into t3_has_ts values (32, 16, 10);

-- And this one should fail.
insert into t3_has_ts values (32, 17, 11);
```

And it does indeed fail. The PostgreSQL error message says that

```
(32, 11) is not present in table "t3"
```

which seems correct.

Comment: Great, this seems to solve my issue, now I just need to figure out how to do something similar with django.